# Socket sends last received packet

Tags: c#, sockets

I've been working on a chat for 2 people. everything is great (i have some exceptions to solve, but no big deal).

but the problem is, when i send a message from the client to server, then server to client, the server sends the last message it got from the client and only after you send again, it sends the right message and the other way around.

Client

```
private Socket _socket;
    private byte[] _buffer;
    private bool ok = false;
    private ListBox _listbox;

    public ClientSocket(ListBox list)
    {
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _listbox = list;
    }

    public void Connect(string ipAddress, int port)
    {
        _socket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port), ConnectedCallback, null);
        if(ok)
            Item("Connected to the server!");
        else Item("Could not Connect to the server!");

    }

    public void SendMessage(string text)
    {
        _buffer = new byte[1024];
        _buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
        _socket.BeginSend(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, SentCallback, null);
    }

    private void ConnectedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        if (_socket.Connected)
        {
            _socket.EndConnect(result);
            _buffer = new byte[1024];
            _socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceivedCallback, null);
            ok = true;
        }
    }

    private void ReceivedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        //_buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufLength = _socket.EndReceive(result);
        //byte[] packet = new byte[bufLength];
        //Array.Copy(_buffer, packet, packet.Length);
        Array.Resize(ref _buffer, bufLength);
        Item(PacketHandler.Handle(_buffer, _socket));
        //PacketHandler.Handle(packet, _socket);

        _buffer = new byte[1024];
        _socket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceivedCallback, null);
    }

    private void SentCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        _socket.EndSend(result);
        //_buffer = new byte[1024];
    }

    public void Item(string text)
    {
        if (_listbox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            _listbox.Invoke(new Action<string>(Item), text);
            return;
        }
        _listbox.Items.Add(text);
    }
```

server

```
        private Socket _socket;
    private Socket _client;
    private byte[] _buffer = new byte[1024];
    private ListBox _listbox;
    public ServerSocket(ListBox list)
    {
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _listbox = list;
    }

    public void Bind(int port)
    {
        _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
        Item("Server Started");
    }
    public void Listen(int backlog)
    {
        _socket.Listen(backlog);
        Item("Listening...");
    }
    public void Accept()
    {
        _socket.BeginAccept(AcceptedCallback, null);
    }
    public void SendMessage(string text)
    {
        _buffer = new byte[1024];
        _buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text);
        _client.BeginSend(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, SentCallback, null);
    }

    private void AcceptedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        _client = _socket.EndAccept(result);
        _buffer = new byte[1024];
        _client.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceivedCallback, _client);
        //_listbox.Items.Add("Accepted User" + _socket.LocalEndPoint.AddressFamily.ToString() + " ");
        //Accept();
    }

    private void ReceivedCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            //_client = result.AsyncState as Socket;
            int bufLength = _client.EndReceive(result);
            //byte[] packet = new byte[bufferSize];
            //Array.Copy(_buffer, packet, packet.Length);
            Array.Resize(ref _buffer, bufLength);
            Item(PacketHandler.Handle(_buffer, _client));
            //Item(PacketHandler.Handle(packet, clientSocket));
            //_listbox.Items.Add(PacketHandler.Handle(packet, clientSocket));
            _buffer = new byte[1024];
            _client.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReceivedCallback, _client);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            Item(("User " + _client.LocalEndPoint.ToString() + " has disconnected"));
        }
    }

    private void SentCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        _client.EndSend(result);
        //_buffer = new byte[1024];
    }
    public void Item(string text)
    {
        if (_listbox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            _listbox.Invoke(new Action<string>(Item), text);
            return;
        }
        _listbox.Items.Add(text);
    }
```

cant find a way to fix it, is my code correct?
btw im not a native speaker so bear with my understanding problems :D

Comment: sounds like you have a Sync issue going on .. have you googled any of the examples online CodeProject has some awesome working examples

Comment: @DJKRAZE i didnt really understand codeproject examples, most of them wont even load on my pc for some reason

Comment: A simple way to get some progress with this problem is probably to use dedicated send and receive buffers.

Comment: Side note (not really related to your problem): You might think about using Encoding.Default. If it happens that the server and the client use different encodings, you or your users will have plenty of fun...

Answer (score 1):

_buffer member variable is being used for all send/receive/accept operations. This can cause serious problems, try using separate member buffer variable for each operation.